# Splitting up repetitive tasks into different steps & procedures

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on some code and one step is finding quite a lot of rows, about 40 or so. This made me wonder when I should break up code more, that is writing separate/smaller procedures, and what is best practice there. Total beginner question, but if I don't ask it, I'll never build good habits.

In the beginning I simply used `Range.Find` and copy-pasted it however many times I needed it. It looked like this:

```
Public fRowType As Long
Public fRowClosing As Long
Public fRowHPPlanDate As Long
Public fRowLoan As Long
Public fRowDoS As Long

Sub MainProcedure()
   Dim wsData As Worksheet

   Set wsData = ActiveSheet
   Call DefiningRows(wsData)
End Sub

Sub DefiningRows(ws As Worksheet) 
    fRowType = ws.Range("A:A").Find("Type", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    fRowClosing = ws.Range("A:A").Find("Closing", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    fRowHPPlanDate = ws.Range("A:A").Find("Holding Period Plan Date (BP)", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    fRowLoan = ws.Range("A:A").Find("End of Loan", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    fRowDoS = ws.Range("A:A").Find("Date of Sale", LookAt:=xlPart).Row
    'about 30-40 more lines of the same
 End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't textbook coding, for example I added the `LookAt:=` only later on and then had to do that ~40 times. Writing a function for this seems like the logical choice. Also, I need to find rows just like that later on in the code, so I could use the function there, too. I wrote it like this (`MainProcedure` is as above and won't change):

```
Sub DefiningRows(ws As Worksheet)
     fRowType = FindRow("Type", ws.Range("A:A"))
     fRowClosing = FindRow("Closing", ws.Range("A:A"))
     fRowHPPlanDate = FindRow("Holding Period Plan Date (BP)", ws.Range("A:A"))
     fRowLoan = FindRow("End of Loan", ws.Range("A:A"))
     fRowDoS = FindRow("Date of Sale", ws.Range("A:A"))
    'about 30-40 more lines of the same
End Sub   

Function FindRow(ByVal searchTerm As String, ByVal searchRange As Range, Optional ByVal partOrWhole As Variant = xlWhole)
    FindRow = searchRange.Find(searchTerm, LookAt:=partOrWhole).Row
End Function
```

1. First question: I mentioned I would call the function not just in what I'm showing you, but also in later subs. Would that actually be a good reason to write it as a separate function? Because the way I am looking at it, something like `fRowType = ws.Range("A:A").Find("Type", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row` is just one line, fairly readable; calling the function is one line, too, but with a separate procedure, which makes it more complicated (not that it's complicated in this case, but it's one step more when stepping through the code).
2. My second question is: Should I replace the repetitive lines of code in `DefiningRows` with a loop? That is, fill an array with the strings I'm looking for (`"Type"`, `"Closing"` etc) and then loop through it. I assume the answer is yes and filling the array would look something like this:

ub

```
Sub FillArray()
     Dim arr As Variant
     arr = Array("Type", "Closing", "Holding Period", "End of Loan", "Date of Sale", "Share", _
     "Object Number", "Object Type", "Object Owner", "Country", "City", "Construction Year", _
     "Main Usage", "Equity", "Borrowed Capital") 'again, there are actually a lot more variables here
End Sub
```

3. Here, too, I wonder about readability because you have line after line of variable names. Maybe declaring variables is an even better example of this: In the picture below, I declare the rows one by one below each other, for the ranges, however, I am more...um, space-efficient. Is there a consensus what's better or is it up to personal preference?

[image]

**edit:**

Here is the data structure I am working with. The columns represent real estate objects and the rows (= what I am searching for) are various characteristics. The whole point of the macro, which isn't displayed here, is using it for conditional formatting to highlight errors and inconsistencies. There are different rules for different characteristics. What this means is that I focus completely on the rows, i.e. the characteristics and where one starts and ends. I don't need to know anything about the columns except how many there are because the conditional formatting is simply applied to all columns.

[image]

Comment: You should really ask one thing per question. Brief answers - (1) not sure you need a function (2) yes (3) use an array.

Comment: I'd check that `FIND` actually finds something - an error will get raised if you try and return the row number of a cell that wasn't found.

Comment: @SJR Thank you. Regarding (3): What do you mean? Can I somehow mass-declare variables with an array?

Comment: Instead of 20 variables, declare one array `dim a(1 to 20)`. You've still got to fill them of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question that should come up is what happens if your search is unsuccessful. That leads you to this function.

```
Function FindRow(ByVal searchTerm As String, _
                 ByVal searchRange As Range, _
                 Optional ByVal PartOrWhole As Long = xlWhole) As Long
    
    Dim Fnd As Range
    
    Set Fnd = searchRange.Find(searchTerm, LookAt:=PartOrWhole)
    On Error Resume Next
    FindRow = Fnd.Row
End Function
```

It will return 0 if the search was unsuccessful. Of course, your function call should deal with the possibility that 0 is returned.

However, the above function is awkward to call, requiring repeated length range definitions. In reality you need to pass a column and, to make the function versatile, a worksheet. Then you should increase your demand on the function to limit the search to the inhabited part of the column. With these aspects the function isn't a one-liner anymore, and the calling procedure shrinks accordingly.

```
Function FindRow2(ByVal searchTerm As String, _
                  ByVal Clm As Long, _
                  Optional Ws As Worksheet, _
                  Optional ByVal PartOrWhole As XlLookAt = xlWhole) As Long
    
    Dim searchRng   As Range            ' the range to search
    Dim Fnd         As Range            ' the found match
    
    If Ws Is Nothing Then Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        Set searchRng = .Range(.Cells(2, Clm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Clm).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Set Fnd = searchRng.Find(searchTerm, LookAt:=PartOrWhole)
    if Not Fnd is Nothing then FindRow2 = Fnd.Row
End Function
```

Note: I have demonstrated two methods of letting the function return 0 if Fnd isn't found. I also informed that xlWhole is an xlLookAt enumeration and therefore a Long, not a Variant.

Your question makes it hard to see what you intend to do but creating dozens of ranges isn't the way. If there are dozens of anything, combine them into one array, as you already started to do. But the array shouldn't be the tool. It should be the result. Take your array `arr = Array("Type", "Closing", "Holding Period", "End of Loan", "Date of Sale", "Share", _ "Object Number", "Object Type", "Object Owner", "Country", "City", "Construction Year", _ "Main Usage", "Equity", "Borrowed Capital")`

What is it that you so describe? Perhaps a loan? So, the name of the array is `Loan`. Say, `Loan` has 30 elements: Loan(1), Loan(2), Loan(3) etc. So you set up an enumeration. I always name enumeration with 3 characters starting with N, followed by 2 characters indicating its purpose. So you I might name it `Nln`.

```
Enum Nln
   NlnType = 1
   NlnClose
   NlnHold
   NlnEnd          ' if no value is assigned the enumeration adds 1 to the previous
   ' etc
End Enum
```

So, now you could assign your search results to Loan(NlnType), Loan(NlnClose), Loan(NlnHold) etc. You could create a matching array with search criteria (perhaps the one you already have) and feed them to a loop that calls *FindRow*. But *FindRow* is a means, not an end. Loan(NlnType) should hold the *Type*, not the row number where *Type* is found or even the range.

All of the above looks very much like `Type` the VBA construct. The example they give is the `Type' by the name of *Employee* where for each *Employee* you have named properties like Name, Age, Gender, Start date, Salary etc. This might work more efficiently for you than the array solution I have described. It's easier to access the data but unwieldy to build in a loop.

In principle you are on the right path: invest more time in preparation with the aim of writing more efficient code.

Comment: Thank you! Your notes and modifications for `Funciton FindRow` make sense to me. 

I'm struggling a bit with the `Enum`, but I think this might be my fault because I didn't say what the purpose of this is - which I did for a reason, I can't give you the data I am working with and so I tried to keep the scope of my question limited. I added additional information to my question - maybe you could read it and tell me if `Enum` makes sense to use here since I don't actually bother with what info each column stores, it's all about the rows.

Comment: An enumeration is the most efficient way of naming numeric variables. The way it looks to me they make perfect sense for your use. Rows 1 thru 13 are named. You have no need to search for them. Enumerate them and dispense with the Find function.